# Trending Topics Using Twitter Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, twitter

I keep getting: **undefined method `trends' for Twitter::REST::Trends:Module** when I implement the twitter gem.

```
require "twitter"
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
    def home
        client = Twitter::REST::Trends
        @trends =client.trends(id=1, options={})
    end
end
```

I'm pretty new to Rails so there's probably something stupid I'm missing, but I can't seem to find the right solution anywhere online. Per my understanding client.trends(id=1, options={}) should be an Enumerable in the documentation http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/Trends . Any idea what it can be? Thanks everyone for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same question and found your post. Here's what worked for me.

```
class TwitterApi

def self.trending_tweets
client.trends(id=1, options = {})
end

def self.client
@client ||= Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
config.consumer_key        = ""
config.consumer_secret     = ""
end
end
end
```

Replace the key and secret with yours and then call TwitterApi.trending_tweets.to_h in your app. I think it returns as a string so I  converted it to a hash in order to access it.